# Infinite scrolling jQuery, MVC 5, EF6

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a products page, and on this page can be up to 200 items, I would like to implement infinite scrolling, like on Twitter or Facebook. Here is the Index view:

```
@model IEnumerable<AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels.DisplayProductsViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2>Products - Necklaces</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div id="container">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="itemcontainer">
            @Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.Id })
            <br />

            <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</div>
            <div><img src="@item.Image.ImagePath" alt="@item.Image.AltText" /></div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div>
                Quantity: <input type="text" id="quantity" style="width:50px;" />&nbsp;
                <button class="addtocart" type="button" data-id="@item.Id">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
            <div style="height:35px;"></div>
        </div>

    }
</div>
```

And the Index method in my ProductsController:

```
private AccessorizeForLessEntities entities = new AccessorizeForLessEntities();

// GET: /Products/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var products = entities.Products.Include(p => p.ProductImage).OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid());

    IEnumerable<DisplayProductsViewModel> model = products.Select(p => new DisplayProductsViewModel()
    {
        Id = p.ProductId,
        Name = p.ProductName,
        Image = p.ProductImage,
        Price = p.ProductPrice
    }).ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

Can someone show me an example on how I can accomplish this please?

Comment: You need an event handler for when the scroll position reaches a point at which you want to load in more content. You then need to 'ask the server' for the next set of items in javascript. You then need to append these items to the DOM.

Comment: There are plenty of jquery plugins that you can use.